# How to set Material UI Fab to Outline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to use the outline variant for the `fab button` in `material ui`

```
<Fab variant="here i see rounded || extended" color="primary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
  <KeyboardArrowUp />
</Fab>
```

is there a way i could use the outline version and still inherit material ui ripple effect and other styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot have outline version for that. But you can always write CSS for that. I had a [simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rxt2q?file=/demo.tsx) for this
**Edit**: here are the code

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
      }
    },
    fabStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      color: theme.palette.primary.light,
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        color: "white"
      }
    }
  })
);

export default function FloatingActionButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.fabStyle}>
        <AddIcon />
      </Fab>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to inject classes into the Fab component. You can refer to this link for more information [Customizing Components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

```js
<Fab 
    classes={{
      root: classes.root, // class name, e.g. `classes-nesting-root-x`
      label: classes.label, // class name, e.g. `classes-nesting-label-x`
    }}
    variant="here i see rounded || extended" color="primary" size="small"     aria-label="scroll back to top">
  <KeyboardArrowUp />
</Fab>
```